# How to hide an included php page with css based on media size

Tags: php, responsive-design, media-queries, php-include

I am trying to update my site to responsive. I have several includes in php on a page. Using media queries sizes I want to hide one of them when it is phone size. Is it possible to hide this with css?

```
<?php include('slideshow.html'); ?>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can place a div before php file include , and hide it on mobile resolution .
Like following example .

```
<div class="slide_show">
<?php include('slideshow.html'); ?> 
</div>
```

css

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.slide_show {
   display:none;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that, added important, then visibility important. No success. then I went into the file and wrapped the code with the div and still no success.

Comment: <div class="slide_show">
   <?php include('slideshow.html'); ?> 
</div>                                                                                                                        Then in css                                                                                    <!-- Hide slideshow on phones -->
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.slide_show {
   display:none !important;
  visibility:hidden !important;
}
}

Comment: add <style type="text/css"> tag before css .  like this ...........  <div class="slide_show"> 
<?php include('slideshow.html'); ?> </div>
 Then in css <!-- Hide slideshow on phones -->
 <style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { 
    .slide_show { 
        display:none !important; 
        visibility:hidden !important; } }
  </style>

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear the style is in a css and then I have this on top of the main file with the include <link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: I check your <link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> . there is nothing wrong in this file . u can check your file is include or not . by check view page source code on browser and search your file link  in source code .